# F# on .NET micro

Tags: f#, .net-micro-framework

Does F# run with .NET Micro?

I have in mind things like the .NET gadgeteer of Microsoft Research Cambridge, or Netduino, the .NET micro version of the Arduino board.

Comment: not an answer but I know the latest firmware (4.2) and sdk support VB.net so adding languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the official answer is C# only.

Comment: do  you have a source for this?

Comment: I was looking for something online--I just seem to recall an MS employee said C# only